# What is a good auto-generated key for a federated database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am about to split a large database into a bunch of federated instances.  Currently, most of the primary keys are auto-generated identity ints.  Obviously, that's not going to work in a federated setup.

I've read people using auto-generated GUIDs to replace the ints, but that data type has well-known performance sapping problems on its own.

What are some of the strategies I can use for having unique values for primary keys across federated members?

Comment: See this for a start: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/09/trouble-keys/

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to perform a hash on some existing value or combination of values, for instance the user's login name and autogenerated identity (int):

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), 
        HashBytes('SHA1', UserName + CAST(UserId AS VARCHAR)) ,2)
    AS FederatedIdentity
FROM Users
```

This way the value would be consistent across databases. You could persist the hash in a table; I usually create a view to work with generated columns like this.